# How to pivot table in SQL partitioned by ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table

| date | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1 | 5 |
| 02/01/2022 | 1 | 2 |
| 03/01/2022 | 1 | 0 |
| 04/01/2022 | 1 | 9 |
| 01/01/2022 | 2 | 10 |
| 01/01/2022 | 4 | 4 |
| 02/01/2022 | 4 | 9 |

I want to pivot the table so that each row for each id has the previous 5 values as columns so that the transformed table is:

| id | value | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | None | None | None | None | None |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | None | None | None | None |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 5 | None | None | None |
| 1 | 9 | 0 | 2 | 5 | None | None |
| 2 | 10 | None | None | None | None | None |
| 4 | 4 | None | None | None | None | None |
| 4 | 9 | 4 | None | None | None | None |

Is there an elegant dynamic way to produce this desired table?

Comment: What determines, in your table, that `5` is the "first" value for `id` `1`? Why not `9` or `2`?

Comment: @Larnu there is another date column which determines the order of the rows--sorry for not mentioning it. Will update

Comment: You need to include that column in your sample data. I seems, however, that `LAG` is what you need here.

Comment: `02/01/2022` <-- ugh, this format is awful. It may not matter in this specific case but do you know how hard it is for readers to know if you mean January 2nd or February 1st?

Answer (score 1):

You need `LAG()` and a column, which defines the order of the rows:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   [value], 
   [value1] = LAG([value], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] ASC),
   [value2] = LAG([value], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] ASC),
   [value3] = LAG([value], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] ASC),
   [value4] = LAG([value], 4) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] ASC),
   [value5] = LAG([value], 5) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date] ASC)
FROM Data d
ORDER BY [id], [date]
```